# How to automate testing a geo-location based menu for a different location from where I live?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to get a page showing information based on where I live to show information for another location?

I'm using chromedriver and selenium

I'm in Sri Lanka so whenever I start chromedriver and navigate to https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending it shows me the trending list for *my* country of Sri Lanka

How could I get the list for a different country, such as USA or India.

Comment: Seems to be this is not relevant to here.

Comment: May be i just have to change the location from the right side menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for "popular in united states". This gives a channel that consists of trending videos for USA.
The channel is: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4zkuKZ8MUpONVT0lDdyu7g

The same way you can search for "popular in india", which gives you this channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAh9DbAZny_eoGFsYlH2JZw

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried googling it? I get results like this:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-my-trending-location-in-YouTube

Answer (score 1):

When I've tested application that use Geolocation, I've always used a proxy service, like [WonderProxy](https://wonderproxy.com/), to route traffic to the country I need to test in. This means I don't have to worry about my tests (automated or exploratory) failing due to me being unable to set the proper location. I've built these into my automated GUI tests using Selenium, using the proxy API and then it just works.